# isEqualNode fails with differing html whitespace

Tags: javascript, html

I have found unexpected behavior with the method Node.isEqualNode() when I use html strings that use different whitespace. With or without the whitespace the html structure is equivalent but the innerText attribute has differing values.

This is for testing purposes only so don't downvote for html strings!

```js
var html = `<table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>a</td>
                  <td>b</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>`

var div_1 = document.createElement('div')
div_1.innerHTML = html

var div_2 = document.createElement('div')
div_2.innerHTML = html.replace(/ |\n/g, '')  // removes whitespace

console.log(div_1)
console.log(div_2)
console.log(div_1.isEqualNode(div_2)) // false
```

The div_1.innerText contains all the whitespace along with a and b while div_2.innerText only contains a and b.

This seems like odd behavior and I want to know if this is intended behavior.

Comment: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-equals so, yes it is intended behavior

Comment: Thanks! So, besides removing the whitespace or having a custom function to ignore innerText there is no way to compare elements created in this way?

Comment: afaik yes (comment needs to be longer to post it, even the rest of the comment is irrelevant)

Answer (score 1):

I think this makes sense. In html, whitespace between elements has meaning. Not in the specific table you've provided, but usually/often it does.

But note also that non-lexical whitespace *is* ignored during the `isEqualNode` check, which is good!

Here's an example (and [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esroxtf3/)) demonstrating both cases:

```
var html = [
    `<span>hello</span> <span>world</span>`,
    `<span>hello</span><span>world</span>`,
    `<span
   >hello</span><span
>world</span>`,
];

var divs = [];
html.forEach((x) => {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = x;
    divs.push(div);
});

divs.forEach((x, i) => {
    console.log(i);
    divs.forEach((y, j) => {
        if (j !== i) {
            console.log(`${i}:${j} -- ${x.isEqualNode(y)}`);
        }
    });
});
```

That code is borderline hipster with all the `i` and `y` and `forEach`, but is still a useful demo, I think.

The first two are different -- we can see that. If it was html, the display *would be* different.

| html | output in browser |
| --- | --- |
| `<span>hello</span> <span>world</span>` | `hello world` |
| `<span>hello</span><span>world</span>` | `helloworld` |

The third has whitespace *but in a way that evaluates to the exact same meaning as the second*.

```
<span
   >hello</span><span
>world</span>
```

The second and third produce `helloworld` and `helloworld` (no space) when rendered!

And that's the output we get:

```
0
"0:1 -- false"
"0:2 -- false"
1
"1:0 -- false"
"1:2 -- true"
2
"2:0 -- false"
"2:1 -- true"
```

<sup>Guess I didn't need to compare half of those as they're repeats, but you get the point.</sup>

There's another example that shows how `DOMParser` splits things in situations like this one into text nodes [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41714780/1028230).

---

Now what bugs me is that the same thing happens in XML, where, I think, even what Oracle calls [insignificant whitespace](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/wang-whitespace.html#:%7E:text=Significant%20whitespace%20is,of%20the%20document.) still produces a false in `isEqualNode`.